# About deriving the multi-trace index in terms of the single-trace index

Tags: quantum-field-theory, string-theory, mathematical-physics, phase-transition, partition-function

This question is in reference to [this paper](http://jp.arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0310285)

Combining their equations 5.2, 5.3, 5.6 and 5.7 one seems to be looking at the integral/partition function,

$Z(x) = \prod_{n=1}^{n =\infty}\left [    \int d\rho_n e^{-N^2\frac{\rho_n^2}{n}(1 - I_L(x,n))} \right ]$

where $I_L(x,n) = z_B(x^n) + (-1)^{n+1}z_F(x^n)$

("x" is the fugacity, $z_B$ and $z_F$ are single particle Bosonic and Fermionic partition functions respectively and $\rho_n$ are Fourier components of the eigenvalue density on the circle of the gauge group $U(N \rightarrow \infty)$)

-I would like to know as to how in the large N limit does this become their claimed equation 5.10,

$Z(x) = \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1 - I_L(x,n)}$

Comment: At least provide a link if you're going to ask people to read a paper for you...

Comment: Its this paper http://jp.arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0310285

Comment: But I guess the issue is of some mathematical trick here and there probably isn't any physics here - the paper just brushes over this calculation in a line or so.

Comment: Screams for Laplace's method/steepest descent, don't you think?

Comment: @Vibert By Laplace's method I guess you mean the expression,$Lim_{N -> \infty} \int _a ^b e^{Nf(x)}dx \sim \sqrt{\frac{2\pi }{N\vert f''(x_0)\vert} }e^{Nf(x_0)}$ where $x_0$ is a global maximum of $f$ in the interval $[a,b]$. But clearly doing this doesn't give the answer in this case. here one would think of $f(\rho_n) = -\frac{\rho_n^2}{n}(1- I_L(x,n))$ and "N" is $N^2$ here and it maximizes at $rho_n = 0$ for $x$ below the Hagedorn transition temperature. Now using the above then one gets $\prod _{n=1}^\infty \sqrt{\frac{n \pi}{N^2(1-I_L(x,n))}}$ - and thats not what is claimed!

Comment: First of all, they renormalize the partition function en route (just below Eq. 5.10), so that takes care of any (divergent) prefactors $\sim \prod n \pi /N$. Are you sure that $\rho_n$ is a single real variable? If it's a complex variable (seems more logical) then you're out of the woods.

Comment: Also, please refrain from saying things like "this clearly doesn't give the right answer" if you don't understand what is going on. Other people are trying to help you in their spare time by looking at 90-page papers, so when you don't understand their comments it's nicer to ask about any misunderstanding than to criticise their suggestions straight off the bat.

Comment: @Vibert Apologies if I sounded critical! That wasn't my intention at all! Very sincere apologies! All I wanted to say is that I had already tried this steepest-descent method and I didn't get the answer! Seems I missed something obvious! Apologies once again. And thanks a lot for pointing out this silly error!

Comment: But on a technical note - why do you think $\rho_n$ is complex? Its defined as $\rho_n = \int_0 ^{2\pi} d\theta \rho(\theta) cos(n\theta)$ and $\rho(\theta)$ is a density on the circle normalized as $\int _{-\pi}^\pi d\theta \rho(\theta) = 1$. $\theta$ is a real number (angle).

Comment: @Vibert If $e^{i\alpha_i}$ are the eigenvalues of the $U(N_c)$ matrix then it would be perfectly valid to define $\rho(\theta) = \frac{1}{N_c}\sum_{i=1}^{i=N_c} \delta(\theta - \alpha_i)$. Isn't it real then?

Comment: Hi, apologies accepted of course, it's just a matter of making this forum as nice as possible. I don't have time to look into the matter any further now, but if you look at Eq. 5.6, the authors write $|\rho_n|^2$ (with abs. value bars). That seems a solid indication that the $\rho_n$ must be complex, or at least a starting point for figuring out what's going on.

Comment: @Vibert Just above 5.5 the authors clearly say that ``$\rho$ must be everywhere non-negative" - hence from this statement its hard to see how $\rho_n$ could become complex! $\rho_n$ is just an integral of $\rho$ with $cos(n\theta)$.